# How do I ? Make sure that `gem install sdoc -v '0.4.1'` succeeds before bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to update after switching ruby versions. Here's what I get after I run bundle update:

`Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/sdoc.bat
 An error occurred while installing sdoc (0.4.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
 Make sure that gem install sdoc -v '0.4.1'` succeeds before bundling.

I tried searching for the error in google and stack overflow with a bunch of dead ends. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm running windows 7, ruby 2.0.0p598, and rails 4.1.8
Thanks

Comment: looks like you don't have permission to write to wherever the gem is being installed

Comment: can I change that in my console with a command prompt to change the permission of the file? I ran as admin and still got the same message?

Comment: I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but just to give you some honest advice because I used to be in your shoes, I recommend using Linux or Max OS when working with Rails.  The ecosystem is riddled with so many gems written with native c-extensions that's its almost impossible to intelligibly do serious production work in it.  Not that I want to discourage you because I do want this to change, but it's an uphill battle: https://gist.github.com/KelseyDH/11198922#file-ruby_rails_windows-md

Comment: I appreciate it and I'm saving up to buy a mac. Been down this road too many times.